# ActiveRecord query interface and map

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to map an AR relation in a specific data structure (to be rendered as JSON) and I can't make it work, for some reason the relations are always nil

```
Client.includes(:fixed_odds_account, person: [:phones, :emails]).map do |client|
  {
    id: client.id,
    uri: client.uri,
    updated_at: client.updated_at,
    balance: client.fixed_odds_account.current_balance,
    email: client.person.emails.pluck(:address),
    first_name: client.person.first_name,
    last_name: client.person.last_name,
    number: client.person.phones.pluck(:number)
  }
```

I'd expect this to return an array of hashes, but it always fails on the "person" relationship, which is apparently nil (and it is not).
What's weird is that if I remove the Hash and just puts client.person I can see my data.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#joins`. With `#includes` you might be hitting a Client without Person as it uses left outer join. You might also want to add `#uniq` to remove duplicates.

```
Client.joins(:fixed_odds_account, person: [:phones, :emails]).uniq.map #code omitted
```